# Laravel voyager : How to display only non-admin in dropdownlist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, voyager

I am using la-ravel 5.7 and voyager panel current version. In one module, defining all relationship through bread. Everything is working fine the only problem is I want to display `users` with role `normalUser` and block all others in drop down lists which is belongs to table `role`.

How can I do this ?

[image: Reference Image:]

Comment: did you try to override edit.blade.php?

Comment: @AliÖzen not yet. Is there any in build setting for that or if i am overriding it is it good way to just simple change the dropdown lists ?

Comment: @Javed i think you must edit your blade file of voyager... See this: https://voyager.readme.io/v0.11/docs/overriding-views

Answer (score 1):

@Javed I have been using this for generating active data in the list. This is an old solution, they have changed the relationship in the new version. see this: [voyager.readme.io/docs/relationships](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/relationships)

## Actual steps to follow are:

1. Update the **Bread** by removing the **Relationship** field
2. Change the **user_id** column to **DropDown**
3. Add

   ```
   { 
       "relationship": { 
           "key": "id", 
           "label": "name"
       } 
   }
   ```

   to **Field Option** for that user_id field in bread.
4. Later add the new function **UserIdList** on your **User model**

   ```
   public function authorIdList(){
       return User::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at')->get();
   }
   ```

Comment: i didnt find so posted